# Message passing between processes using multiprocessing module

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ipc, multiprocessing, communication

What's the recommended way of sending message from a worker process to another randomly selected (worker or master) process? One approach that I can think of is using [Pipes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues), but since it can only create a pipe between two selected processes, I need to create a pipe for each process pair. This doesn't seem so practical. What I want is to create a complete graph between processes and select one of the pipes randomly.

Comment: Pipes are useful when process relation are parent/child. Otherwise use shared-memory. If message is just an signal to some event then use Linux signals. **Which IPC you uses, Depends on your need!**

Answer (score 4):

You could use Queue in order to communicate among your processes by maintaining some convention in your queue.Your could find the details on using Queue [here](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/queue.html#queue.Queue).

P.S :- As mentioned [here](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html) Queues are thread and process safe.

Comment: @polerto if you feel the answer is correct please mark it as correct.